# How to animate 100's of objects cast modifier's Factor

Tags: animation, modifiers

I am trying to animate the factor of the cast modifier of 100 objects in my scene. I was able to use ctrl+L to copy the modifier to all objects, but it doesn't copy the keyframes with it.

Is there a way to keyframe the cast modifier of all objects without doing it manually for each?

Comment: you could make all the vertices converge in the Graph Editor? Or with a script?

Comment: The graph editor contains no cast modifier keyframes unless I manually add a keyframe for each object. My question is how to add all of these keyframes.

Comment: my bad you're right you need at least one keyframe

Comment: ah looks like I could ctrl+L to copy animation data

Comment: oh yes of course, so put it as an answer!

Comment: Also consider using drivers. Eg one scene property can be animated & then used as a target  to drive all modifiers. Changing the properties animation will be reflected by all driven by it... as opposed to all objects sharing the same action (the result of link animation data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ctrl+L allows you to copy animation data too.